# How to detect the error : This page did not load Google Maps correctly?

Tags: r, google-maps, web, server

Let's say I have a website to check every now and then to see if it works properly and I want to do it automatically with the help of coding in R.

As an example, I might do the following every hour to check whether it gives me 404 Not Found error.

```
library(httr)

r <- GET("http://httpbin.org/status/404")
http_error(r)
[1] TRUE

status_code(r)
[1] 404
```

But my webpage uses Google Maps and sometimes I detect the following error:

**This page did not load Google Maps correctly.**

Is there anyone who knows how to detect such an error in a way without needing to browsing the webpage and in the same manner as explaind above?

Comment: Google Maps relies _heavily_ on asynchronous javascript execution to work so you'd need to use something like `splashr` or `seleniumPipes` (or a cpl other, similar ) to perform the check.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. I have a question. What does cpl stand for?

Comment: (I use way too many abbreviations) "(or a couple other, similar …)"

Comment: We also have a mobile app version of the webpage that is mentioned in this question. This app sometimes gives errors as well. For instance, once we had server communication error. But while we had this error, there was no issues with the webpage. I would like to ask if there is a possibility to check an app it works properly for example, in the way @hrbrmstr advises me to follow.

Comment: Is this a public app / web page? i.e. can you post the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two scripts. The first one given below checks and if in the case of **This page did not load Google Maps correctly.**, prints the error message using the notifier package. For the basics of RSelenium please consult https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html.
There says that there are three ways to run a Selenium Server. I chose the easist one which is the second one: rsDriver.

```
# To get the message written I use the notifier package, 
# https://github.com/gaborcsardi/notifier 

library(notifier)

# To do the webscraping I use RSelenium 

library(RSelenium)

# To check whether the string contains what I am after I prefer stringr

library(stringr)



rD <- rsDriver(verbose = FALSE)

remDr <- rD$client

remDr$navigate("https:...")

# Wait a little while it is busy with downloading everything

Sys.sleep(120)

# we scrape it and convert it to a character string 

a <- XML::htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])

b <- as(a, "character")

# we check if the string has the error phrase.

result <- str_detect(b, "This page can't load Google Maps correctly")

# if yes, then the following error message is printed.


if (result == TRUE){notify(title = "ERROR",
                       msg = sprintf("This page can't load Google Maps correctly"))}


# to close the client and the server
remDr$close()

rD$server$stop()
```

Below is the second script to automate on specific time points from R itself using the taskscheduler package. In this case the code is executed every 5 minutes.

```
library(taskscheduleR)

myscript <- "the place of the first script"

taskscheduler_create(taskname = "myfancyscript_5min", rscript = myscript,
                 schedule = "MINUTE", starttime = "09:10", modifier = 5)
```